# A problem with changing the color twice with a delay

Tags: javascript

I have recently started my journey with the all Front-End stuff and I wanted to create a simple game similar to "Simon Says" using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

I wanted the app to mark the first field on the green to show the sequence, then - after the short delay - to change it back to the default colour (white). And after same with the second button, third... etc.

As a result I have ended up with this:

```
function showFields() {
    for( var x = 0; x<computerSeq.length; x++) {

        field[computerSeq[x]].style.backgroundColor = "green";

        setTimeout(() => {
            field[computerSeq[x]].style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't work as I thought it would, as the background keeps to be white. I am attaching rest of the code below:
https://codepen.io/jhrwekuh/pen/wYrYgV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're incrementing the loop before your timeout finishes, causing your program to crash due to the fact that the index is undefined.

Inside your timeout, you need to reference `x - 1` rather than `x`:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  field[computerSeq[x - 1]].style.backgroundColor = "white";
}, 1000);
```

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  let computerSeq = [];
  let playerSeq = [];
  const field = document.querySelectorAll('.field');
  const button = document.getElementById('startButton');
  let computerField;
  let roundNumber = 0;
  let failed = 0;
  let running = 0;
  var interval;
  var currentfield;

  function newField() {
    computerField = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    computerSeq.push(computerField);
  }

  function showFields() {
    for (var x = 0; x < computerSeq.length; x++) {
      field[computerSeq[x]].style.backgroundColor = "green";
      setTimeout(() => {
        field[computerSeq[x - 1]].style.backgroundColor = "white";
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    $('#round').text('1');
    roundNumber = 1;
    button.style.display = "none";
    running = 1;

    if (running == 1) {
      newField();
      showFields();
      console.log(computerSeq);
    }

  });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
}

#title {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(0, 75, 145);
}

.game-wrapper {
  background-color: rgb(20, 0, 110);
  text-align: center;
  .table {
    background-color: rgb(0, 71, 165);
    .row {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    #row1 {
      padding-top: 60px;
    }
    #row2 {
      padding-bottom: 60px;
    }
    .field {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: white;
      margin: 5px;
      transition: 500ms ease;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px rgb(78, 78, 78);
    }
    .field:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: rgb(185, 185, 185);
    }
  }
  .info-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 30px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    .score-wrapper {
      margin-right: 30px;
    }
    button {
      background-color: rgb(40, 0, 104);
      border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 26);
      font-size: 25px;
      width: 200px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      transition: 500ms ease;
    }
    button:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .info {
      align-self: center;
      margin-left: 30px;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>The Memo Game</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1 id="title">The Memo Game</h1>
  <div class="game-wrapper">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="row" id="row1">
        <div class="field" id="field1"></div>
        <div class="field" id="field2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" id="row2">
        <div class="field" id="field3"></div>
        <div class="field" id="field4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="info-wrapper">
      <div class="score-wrapper">
        <h3>Round:</h3>
        <p id="score">0</p>
      </div>
      <button id="startButton" type="button">START</button>
      <div class="info">No one's turn</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This can be seen on CodePen **[here](https://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/xyXyLp)**.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `setTimeout` callback will be executed only after `for` loop ends running. That is why the callback of `setTimeout` will receive `x` with the value it will get after loop execution. You can fix this code by using IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) to pass the actual value of `x` into your callback:

`setTimeout((index => () => {
    field[computerSeq[index]].style.backgroundColor = "white";
})(x), 1000);`

[See fixed codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YJrJYR?editors=1111)